# GridView Edit/Delete Not refreshing correctly. ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

Essentially what i'm doing is allowing a user to type in a persons name, press a button and edit/delete a field of choice.

I can edit/delete fine using the default gridview properties. But when I press edit, It reloads back to the default  selectcommand. What i need it to do is to use the textbox's text.

This is how i search for a user

```
 protected void GetUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        query = Session["username"].ToString();  
        string sql = "SELECT [Username], [Job Description] AS Job_Description, [Hours Worked] AS Hours_Worked, [Date], [ID] FROM [TimeData] WHERE ([Username] LIKE '" + query+ "')";
        Response.Write("done");
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sql;
    }
```

So in the page loads i need it to " remember" what i put in before pressing edit.

in the ASPX file i leave the selectcommand blank, and instead set it in the Page_load method

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.Visible = true;
        Session["Username"] = UserBox.Text;
        //Session["Username"] = "rhys";
        query = Session["username"].ToString();
        string sql = "SELECT [Username], [Job Description] AS Job_Description, [Hours Worked] AS Hours_Worked, [Date], [ID] FROM [TimeData]";
        //Response.Write("done");
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sql;   
    }
```

Atm I can get it to appear again, but i'm querying the full table again , not by username

I was looking at a way to maybe postback the variable or something but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
The comments have helped however the button I press

```
  protected void GetUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 query = Session["username"].ToString();
 string sql = "SELECT [Username], [Job Description] AS Job_Description, [Hours Worked] AS Hours_Worked, [Date], [ID] FROM   [TimeData] WHERE ([Username] LIKE '" + query + "')"; 
Response.Write("done");
 SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sql; 

}
```

" No longer returns any changes , would that be because the same code is in the else part of the block after !postback?

Comment: The way your code is currently, your values will get set each time your page loads (especially on postback).  If you don't want that to happen, you've got to wrap your initialization code in a `If (IsPostback == False)

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
        GridView1.Visible = true;
        Session["Username"] = UserBox.Text;
        query = Session["username"].ToString();
        string sql = "SELECT [Username], [Job Description] AS Job_Description, [Hours Worked] AS Hours_Worked, [Date], [ID] FROM [TimeData]";
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sql; 
     } 
}
```

As it stands now your page load is going to overwrite what your event handler has done.

Also, user [parameteriezd queries](http://forums.asp.net/t/1568268.aspx) to protect yourself against SQL injection

Comment: That kinda works. Thanks but the button I press
  protected void GetUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           query = Session["username"].ToString();
           string sql = "SELECT [Username], [Job Description] AS Job_Description, [Hours Worked] AS Hours_Worked, [Date], [ID] FROM [TimeData] WHERE ([Username] LIKE '" + query + "')";
           Response.Write("done");
           SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sql;
        }
"
No longer returns any changes , would that be because the same code is in the else part of the block after !postback?